# Why utf8 encoding of the string gives the string that is unchanged in return

Tags: node.js, utf-8

My code is as shown below:

```
let createCipher = (req, res) => {
    const text = req.body.text;
    let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(utf8.encode(text)).digest('hex');
    res.json({
        status: '200',
        data: hash,
        utf: utf8.encode(text)
    });
}
```

Here, whatever I give as **text** input parameter, the same will be return in the response field **utf**. so is there anything missing from utf8 process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let createCipher = (req, res) => {
    const text = req.body.text;
    //text = "Hello World";

    let hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
    hash.update(utf8.encode(text));

    //or you try
    //let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(utf8.encode(text));

    let data = hash.digest('hex');
    //console.log(data + '  ' + text);
    //console.log("utf8 - byte data : " + utf8.encode(data)+ '  ' + utf8.encode(text));
    res.json({
        status: '200',
        data: hash,
        utf: utf8.encode(data) //data
    });
}

//Output 
//b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5  Hello World                               
//utf8 - byte data : b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5  Hello World
```

Comment: both of them are same. So my question is about if I accept body parameters in "x-www-formurlencoded" then its utf8 will be as it is

Comment: your question is `whatever I give as text input parameter, the same will be returned in the response` like `text` is `hello` and after crypto, it is same as `hello`? please elaborate ...

Comment: yes, I have clearly mentioned in my question that both input and output are the same. So is it because of something missing? or both can be the same

Comment: please check my updated code. your response is definitely encrypted data. read details about utf8 : https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8

Comment: I am running the same code as given by you, but output is **3e25960a79dbc69b674cd4ec67a72c62** not **b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5 ** as per your code snippet

Comment: The exact hash function isn't defined by the language, so you can't expect to get the same results on different platforms or between 32/64-bit versions.